# Efficient way to append bytes to a word and reverse them?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have an array of bytes like this, in Python 2.7 (the actual object is a bytearray, but I write it as a common array for better readability):

```
array = [0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04]
# actual thing is b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'

# its bit representation would be:
bit_array = [0b00000001, 0b00000010, 0b00000011, 0b00000100]
```

I would like to construct another variable, called *word*, that is the combination of the bytes in the array, like this:

```
word = 0x01020304  # this would be a 32-bit int
```

However, in my case, I also need to reverse the bytes (as they are received by another system that works in a reversed bit-order than mine), so instead of the original byte array, I should combine this one in order to obtain what I need:

```
reversed_bit_array = [0b10000000, 0b01000000, 0b11000000, 0b00100000]
#reversed_word = whatever
```

What is the most *efficient* way to do this? The code should be called multiple times in a loop, so it should be as fast as possible. I've tried to use a lookup table but I'm a little confused about the results, so there is definitely something wrong.
Below is my code:

```
a = bytearray([0x01,0x02,0x03, 0x04])
b = 0x01020304 # this is the combined array without reversal
c = 0x10203040 # this is what I want
word = 0

for j in range(len(a)):
    word = word << 8
    word += bitReverseTable256[a[j]] 

print(bin(word))
print(bin(c))

>>0b10000000010000001100000000100000
>>0b10000001000000011000001000000
```

Where `bitReverseTable256` is the following lookup table:

```
bitReverseTable256 = (
    0x00, 0x80, 0x40, 0xC0, 0x20, 0xA0, 0x60, 0xE0, 0x10, 0x90, 0x50, 0xD0, 0x30, 0xB0, 0x70, 0xF0,
    0x08, 0x88, 0x48, 0xC8, 0x28, 0xA8, 0x68, 0xE8, 0x18, 0x98, 0x58, 0xD8, 0x38, 0xB8, 0x78, 0xF8,
    0x04, 0x84, 0x44, 0xC4, 0x24, 0xA4, 0x64, 0xE4, 0x14, 0x94, 0x54, 0xD4, 0x34, 0xB4, 0x74, 0xF4,
    0x0C, 0x8C, 0x4C, 0xCC, 0x2C, 0xAC, 0x6C, 0xEC, 0x1C, 0x9C, 0x5C, 0xDC, 0x3C, 0xBC, 0x7C, 0xFC,
    0x02, 0x82, 0x42, 0xC2, 0x22, 0xA2, 0x62, 0xE2, 0x12, 0x92, 0x52, 0xD2, 0x32, 0xB2, 0x72, 0xF2,
    0x0A, 0x8A, 0x4A, 0xCA, 0x2A, 0xAA, 0x6A, 0xEA, 0x1A, 0x9A, 0x5A, 0xDA, 0x3A, 0xBA, 0x7A, 0xFA,
    0x06, 0x86, 0x46, 0xC6, 0x26, 0xA6, 0x66, 0xE6, 0x16, 0x96, 0x56, 0xD6, 0x36, 0xB6, 0x76, 0xF6,
    0x0E, 0x8E, 0x4E, 0xCE, 0x2E, 0xAE, 0x6E, 0xEE, 0x1E, 0x9E, 0x5E, 0xDE, 0x3E, 0xBE, 0x7E, 0xFE,
    0x01, 0x81, 0x41, 0xC1, 0x21, 0xA1, 0x61, 0xE1, 0x11, 0x91, 0x51, 0xD1, 0x31, 0xB1, 0x71, 0xF1,
    0x09, 0x89, 0x49, 0xC9, 0x29, 0xA9, 0x69, 0xE9, 0x19, 0x99, 0x59, 0xD9, 0x39, 0xB9, 0x79, 0xF9,
    0x05, 0x85, 0x45, 0xC5, 0x25, 0xA5, 0x65, 0xE5, 0x15, 0x95, 0x55, 0xD5, 0x35, 0xB5, 0x75, 0xF5,
    0x0D, 0x8D, 0x4D, 0xCD, 0x2D, 0xAD, 0x6D, 0xED, 0x1D, 0x9D, 0x5D, 0xDD, 0x3D, 0xBD, 0x7D, 0xFD,
    0x03, 0x83, 0x43, 0xC3, 0x23, 0xA3, 0x63, 0xE3, 0x13, 0x93, 0x53, 0xD3, 0x33, 0xB3, 0x73, 0xF3,
    0x0B, 0x8B, 0x4B, 0xCB, 0x2B, 0xAB, 0x6B, 0xEB, 0x1B, 0x9B, 0x5B, 0xDB, 0x3B, 0xBB, 0x7B, 0xFB,
    0x07, 0x87, 0x47, 0xC7, 0x27, 0xA7, 0x67, 0xE7, 0x17, 0x97, 0x57, 0xD7, 0x37, 0xB7, 0x77, 0xF7,
    0x0F, 0x8F, 0x4F, 0xCF, 0x2F, 0xAF, 0x6F, 0xEF, 0x1F, 0x9F, 0x5F, 0xDF, 0x3F, 0xBF, 0x7F, 0xFF
)
```

As it can be seen, the results are not what I expected. I don't know what is wrong, and I also ask myself how efficient is this (I suppose there is a faster way to do it).

Comment: the table doesn't match what you expect. The inverse of 1 isn't 0x40 but 0x80, and so on.

Comment: The `c` about which you state that this is what you want probably isn't: you have only inverted the hexadecimal digits for each byte, which means that you exchanged the four high order bits with the four low order ones. One thing remains unclear to me though: do you want to keep the order of the bytes, but reverse their bits, or reverse the whole 32 bits as a whole?

Comment: From the result you say you want, it looks like you're reversing the two 4-bit nybbles of each byte.

Comment: python or efficient, you have to choose one

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I want to invert only the bits in each byte, but I want to keep the order of the bytes (so the first byte in the array is the same as my first byte, but it should be reversed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you have the following corespondences:

Hex - Decimal - Binary

**0x01** = **1** = **0000 0001**

**0x10** = **16** = **0001 0000**

**0x02** = **2** = **0000 0010**

**0x20** = **32** = **0010 0000**

Now obviously that each half of the byte represents also half of the hex value, and considering the fact that:

**0xFF** = **255** = **1111 1111**

we can safely assume that we can treat each half for some bitwise operations, hence we need to create some masks that will extract each half of the byte.

`A_MASK = 0xF0` which is `11110000` and `B_MASK = 0x0F` which is `00001111`. The `A` is the left half and the `B` is the right half of the byte.

Now we can use these masks to extract the information we need by performing an `AND` operation between the byte value and our masks. The `0000` half of the mask will cancel/even out to 0 the other half which we are not interested in.

After we obtain these halves, we can proceed and shift them by `4` bits to the left and to the right respectively, basically shifting their half position.

In the end we can just perform an `OR` operation which will provide the reverse byte.

Example:

Let's assume we want to reverse the `0x52` to `0x25`.

**0x52** = **0011 0001**

**0101 0010** `AND` **1111 0000** => **0101 0000** (the A imprint)

**0101 0010** `AND` **0000 1111** => **0000 0010** (the B imprint)

Let's shift the imprints

**0101 0000** >> 4 => **0000 0101**

**0000 0010** << 4 => **0010 0000**

Now we can obtain the final byte.

**0000 0101** `OR` **0010 0000** => **0010 0101** = **0x25**

The complete code:

```
initial_values = bytearray([0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04])

print(initial_values.hex())

A_MASK = 0xF0
B_MASK = 0x0F

new_vals = bytearray()
for val in initial_values:
    aprint = val & A_MASK
    bprint = val & B_MASK

    aprint_shift = aprint >> 4
    bprint_shift = bprint << 4
    reversed_val = aprint_shift | bprint_shift
    new_vals.append(reversed_val)

print(new_vals.hex())
```

which will yield:

```
01020304
10203040
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! But trying to print new_vals.hex() gave me an _AttributeError: 'bytearray' object has no attribute 'hex'_, but I managed to do it using the _binascii_
 lib and the following statement: _print (binascii.hexlify(new_vals))_

EDIT: How should I do it if I want to reverse the whole byte?

Comment: @jcf my bad, I did it in python 3

Comment: You can call something like: `print("".join(["{:0x}".format(x) for x in new_vals]))` for python 2.7

Comment: @jcf, you mean like instead of `0x257F` to have `0xF752` ? or `0x7F25` ?

Comment: something like this (I put it in bin because it's easier for me to understand it):
0b011001  ----> 0b100110

Comment: @jcf, yeah so basically you just take the result from the script in my answer and then reverse the bytes themselves like `new_vals = new_vals[::-1]`. Considering the example in my answer `01020304` will result in `40302010`